# C++ Array of Pointers from Array of strings

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I am new to c++ programming and I am currently working on my school project that involves manipulating data stored as a const string array that contains five strings.

Part of the requirements of this project is that I need to create an array of pointers that hold the data stored in the const string array and then create a student object for each of the "students" stored in that array to populate the array of pointers.

I have so far been experimenting with vectors to create the array of pointers, but have consistently hit a brick wall with trying to piece it all together. If someone could give some insight, I would really appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried? Please show your code and tell us exactly what you are having troubles with.

Comment: Here is a pastebin link with the code of my roster header and cpp files, student header and cpp files. I was trying to create a vector of pointers, but ended up just getting extremely confused with the different moving pieces as well as the abstraction of pointers: https://pastebin.com/AiS1G1cP

Answer (score 2):

So, basically you want to create an Array of pointers, where each pointer points to the first char of a string.
The solution to these kind of problems can be dealt with using the code below:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{

    char *fruits[] = {
                         "apple",
                         "mango",
                         "orange",
                         "bananas",
                         "grapes"
                     };

    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf("String = %10s", fruits[i] );
        printf("Address of string's first char = %u\n", fruits[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your solution [is not valid C++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f72c217dda1c6629)

Comment: Why would you only point to the first character? If I need to manipulate this data later is it that the first character is still apart of the location in memory?

Comment: You only need to store the location of first character because you can directly print the whole string without using one by one letter. So when you use the first letter's address, the whole string gets printed